# Функция для подготовки имени исполняемого файла

Tags: php, ffmpeg, exec

Хотел поработать с `exec()` в связке с `ffmpeg`.

```
$dir = "audio2/";
if (is_dir($dir)) {
    if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
            if ($file == '.' || $file == '..') {
                
            } else {
                $name = time();
                exec("ffmpeg -i {$dir}{$file} -c:a copy audio3/{$name}.aac");
            }
        }
        closedir($dh);
    }
}
```

Но на выход получал ошибки связанные с именем файла.

```
comp:/var/www/html/int/audio2$ ffmpeg -i Max David - Vibez (Official Video HD)1080p.mp4 -c:a copy audio3/1636167436.aac
```

bash: синтаксическая ошибка рядом с неожиданным маркером «(»

```
comp:/var/www/html/int/audio2$ ffmpeg -i Max\ David\ -\ Vibez\ \(Official\ Video\ HD\)1080p.mp4
```

Так мне имя файла подставляет терминал. Думал найти функцию подготовки имени файла в интернете, но не вышло. Может у кого-нибудь такая имеется?

Comment: Вопрос так сказать не срочный, всегда можно обойти проблему тем же `rename`, но просто интересно

Comment: Попробуйте заключать имена файлов в двойные кавычки.